# Sed replacement of ip address

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to use sed to replace an one IP address with other. any assistance would be appreciated.

The string in test.1 file is:

```
o=Acc1111 3415 1536 IN IP4 10.201.25.173.
```

I would like to replace only `10.201.25.173.` with `127.0.0.1.`

The desired final string should be:

```
o=Acc1111 3415 1536 IN IP4 127.0.0.1.
```

My sed regular expression is:

```
sed 's/o=.*IN IP4.*/*IN IP4 127.0.0.1./' test.1
```

But that replaces all the string with `IN IP4 127.0.0.1.`.

I need that command in one lined regular expression. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a capture group and backreference to copy the beginning of the line into the replacement, and replace the IP with `127.0.0.1`

```
sed 's/\(o=.*IN IP4 \).*/\1127.0.0.1./' test.1
```

`\(...\)` creates a capture group. In the replacement `\1` is replaced with the part of the input that matched the first capture group, `\2` gets the second capture group, and so on.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you. but i nned a generic solution. that specific IP can be any other IP. i would like to override any given IP

Comment: Wow that was quick! :) Thank you.
Can you explain the syntax?

Comment: I've added an explanation. But it sounds like you need to read a regexp tutorial to understand capture groups.

Comment: Thank you very much Barmar, I will.

Answer (score 2):

A more simple solution is to use `awk` and just replace the last field.

```
awk '/IN IP4/ {$NF="127.0.0.1."}1' file
o=Acc1111 3415 1536 IN IP4 127.0.0.1.
```

This replace the IP to `127.0.0.1.` in all lines whit text `IN IP4`